# How to build a deterministic random plot

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, random

I have this interesting problem, a simple but (apparently) not easy one:

My server is serving a JSON containing a random plot, in the range [-1,+1]. Each value is sent with its corresponding timestamp, here an example of JSON:

```
[
 { 1560765102, -0.53 },
 { 1560765103, -0.54 }, 
 { 1560765104, -0.43 }, 
 { 1560765105, -0.21 }, 
 { 1560765106, -0.11 }, 
 { 1560765107, 0.21 }, 
 { 1560765108, 0.34 }, 
 { 1560765109, 0.2 }, 
]
```

As you can see, the plot is not generated straight from a PRNG (like `Math.rand()`), otherwise it will look like white AWGN noise. Instead, each point value is a function of the previous one. This way the plot looks more like a plausible random temperature signal, which is what I want to show. This is the generator:

```
var rndvalue = 0;
function random(timestamp)
{
    rndvalue += randomDet(timestamp) * 0.2 - 0.1;
    if(rndvalue > 1) rndvalue = 1;
    if(rndvalue < -1) rndvalue = -1;
    return rndvalue;
}
```

`randomDet()` is nothing more than a very simple hash function which gets a timestamp and spits out a real number in the range [-1,+1]. The signal is clamped to -1, +1.

The client requests the plot in a given range, `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp`, the server just loops through all the timestamps in between and builds the JSON:

```
function getPlot(startTick, endTick)
{
    var points = [];
    var t = startTick;

    while(t < endTick)
    {
        var row = { tick: t, value: random(t) };
        points.push(row);
        t++;
    }

    return points;
}
```

The problem is, every time the client asks again for the same timestamp interval, the server returns a different plot (zooming in/out get confusing, as the plot changes every time instead of just being re-scaled accordingly). I'd like to have the plot to be deterministic (i.e. to be always the same, if the same timestamp interval is requested)

**What I tried**

I tried modifying the random() function is such a way that, for every timestamp, it always return the same point value. To do so I had to add a for loop and recompute the entire plot since timestamp = 0 up to the requested timestamp point value. It works but it is very slow, since it's a O(N^2) for every point value, where N is the requested point timestamp.

```
var rndvalue = 0;
function random(tick)
{
    rndvalue = 0;
    for(var t = 0; t < tick; t++)
    {
        rndvalue += randomDet(t) * 0.2 - 0.1;
        if(rndvalue > 1) rndvalue = 1;
        if(rndvalue < -1) rndvalue = -1;
    }
    return rndvalue;
}
```

How can it be done in a more efficient way? Ideally O(1)

Comment: Just `srand(timestamp);` for every random number required.

Comment: @pmg unfortunately my question is not clear enough. If you do that, you don't get a deterministic plot as the rndvalue variable is the current state of the server, and each point value depends on it (since each point value is the sum of a new random value plus the previous one (current rndvalue value))

Comment: Your `randomDet` function simulates some temperature sensor input. Instead of reading sensor data from the past again and again you might think about storing your temperature data after reading once.

Comment: @Gerhardh that could be an option, but I'd need to limit the plot to a given period of time (i.e. minimum start time and maximum end time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by trading computing time for a periodic plot

```
function random(tick)
{
    var rndvalue = 0;
    for(var t = 0; t < (tick % 1000); t++)
    {
        rndvalue += randomDet(t) * 0.2 - 0.1;
        if(rndvalue > 1) rndvalue = 1;
        if(rndvalue < -1) rndvalue = -1;
    }
    return rndvalue;
}
```

This way the plot is deterministic and it takes only a fixed amount of for cycles to output a single value. The downside is that the plot is periodic, with period equal to the fixed number of for cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You don't reset the value of `rndvalue` each time `getPlot()` is called; as a result, `getPlot()` returns different results depending on what value `rndvalue` is when that function is called.  In fact, functions should be as self-contained as possible and not rely on "global" variables.  The following solution uses `randomDet()` directly and avoids the use of "global" variables.  Note that `rndvalue` is now a local variable of `getPlot()`.

```
function getPlot(startTick, endTick)
{
    var points = [];
    var rndvalue = 0;
    var t = startTick;

    while(t < endTick)
    {
        rndvalue += randomDet(t) * 0.2 - 0.1;
        if(rndvalue > 1) rndvalue = 1;
        if(rndvalue < -1) rndvalue = -1;
        var row = { tick: t, value: rndvalue };
        points.push(row);
        t++;
    }

    return points;
}
```